# Trying to remove substrings that start with '@' from the dataframe and then drop columns that have the same username and text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am working on this personal project where I am looking to do the following:

1. Remove substrings that start with @ from a column consisting of texts.
2. Then delete rows that have the same username and the cleaned texts.

The data frame looks like this

```
username      text
A           @john testing this!
B           @john what is up?
A           @smudge @renge testing this!
```

I want the result to be:

```
username      text
A           testing this!
B           what is up?
```

The code I have written for this doesn't seem to work:

```
df['clean_text']=df['text'].str.replace('(@\w+.*?)',"")
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['clean_text', 'username'])
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Edit: Tried replacing the regex with `(@\w+\s*)` as per Quang's answer but the duplicated rows still remain. Also, tried applying
`df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` to strip spaces

Comment: Your regex matches `@smudge @renge testing this!` twice, each time replacing the match with an empty string. So you get two consecutive whitespace characters in the output for that string.

Comment: @Nick after I was your comment, I tried the spaces with the regex Quang mentioned in the answers (@\w+\s*) and strip spaces from the text using df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().
But after drop duplicates, the columns still remain.

Comment: I figured it out, it appears regex was matching correctly, but there were some different hashtags and URLs that made the string unique. I had to remove them all and just have the texts. It works now. All this because one user spammed tweeted the same text multiple times on multiple days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this once.

```
clean_text=[]
for ele in df['text']:
  temp=''
  for ele1 in ele.split():
    if ele1.__contains__('@'):
      pass
    else:
      temp=temp+ele1+' '
  clean_text.append(temp)
df['text']=clean_text
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['text','username'])
```

output:

```
  username            text
0     A          testing this! 
1     B          what is up?
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I kinda a used your solution with some modification to clean other substrings as well and it appeared to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your pattern to capture the optional trailing white spaces:

```
df['clean_text'] = df['text'].str.replace('(@\w+\s*)',"")

df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['clean_text', 'username'])
```

Output:

```
  username                 text     clean_text
0        A  @john testing this!  testing this!
1        B    @john what is up?    what is up?
```

Comment: It is doesn't remove the duplicates. It removes the '@substring' values but the duplicates still exist. I tried to strip all extra spaces as well from the texts, but it doesn't seem to work still.